# How to train model to add new classes?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

My trained model has 10 classes ( ie. output layer has 10 classes). I want to add 3 more classes to it without training the whole model again.
I want to use the old trained model and add new classes to it.

This is the code I had already tried but it shows an error.

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense

base_model = load_model('hand_gest.h5')

new_model = Sequential()

for layer in base_model.layers[:-2]:
    new_model.add(layer)

for layer in new_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

weights_training = base_model.layers[-2].get_weights()
new_model.layers[-2].set_weights(weights_training) 


new_model.add(Dense(units = 3, activation = 'softmax'))
```

But when I train this model it shows the following error.

```
ValueError: You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "max_pooling2d_2" with a  weight list of length 2, but the layer was expecting 0 weights. Provided weights: [array([[-0.01650696,  0.01082378,  0.0149541 , .....
```

Answer (score 2):

As the number of classes is changed from 10 to 13, the last layer of the previous network needs to be changed.

```
base_model = load_model('hand_gest.h5')
base_model.pop() #remove the last layer - 'Dense' layer with 10 units
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
base_model.add(Dense(units = 13, activation = 'softmax'))
base_model.summary() #Check architecture before starting the fine-tuning
```